# SIMPLESAMLPHP Redirect loop with valet

Tags: php, laravel, simplesamlphp, laravel-valet

I am setup the SimpleSAMLphp setup using Laravel Valet  but I am stuck in redirect loop following is my config setting. Please anybody help what did I wrong.  when I try to open the page its ask me to many redirect loop.

Array
(
[baseurlpath] => http://sso.test/public
[application] => Array
(
[baseURL] => http://sso.test
)

```
[tempdir] => /tmp/simplesaml
[certdir] => cert/
[technicalcontact_name] => XXXXX
[technicalcontact_email] => XXXXXX.com
[timezone] => 
[secretsalt] => 12345654321122
[auth.adminpassword] => 123
[trusted.url.domains] => Array
    (
    )

[trusted.url.regex] => 
[enable.http_post] => 
[assertion.allowed_clock_skew] => 180
[debug] => Array
    (
        [saml] => 1
        [backtraces] => 1
        [validatexml] => 
    )

[showerrors] => 1
[errorreporting] => 1
[logging.level] => 5
[logging.handler] => syslog
[logging.facility] => 168
[logging.processname] => simplesamlphp
[logging.logfile] => simplesamlphp.log
[statistics.out] => Array
    (
    )

[proxy] => 
[database.dsn] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saml
[database.username] => simplesamlphp
[database.password] => secret
[database.options] => Array
    (
    )

[database.prefix] => 
[database.driver_options] => Array
    (
    )

[database.persistent] => 
[database.secondaries] => Array
    (
    )

[enable.saml20-idp] => 
[enable.adfs-idp] => 
[module.enable] => Array
    (
        [exampleauth] => 
        [core] => 1
        [admin] => 1
        [saml] => 1
    )

[session.duration] => 28800
[session.datastore.timeout] => 14400
[session.state.timeout] => 3600
[session.cookie.name] => SimpleSAMLSessionID
[session.cookie.lifetime] => 1800
[session.cookie.path] => .sso.test
[session.cookie.domain] => .sso.test
[session.cookie.secure] => 1
[session.phpsession.cookiename] => SimpleSAML
[session.phpsession.savepath] => /
[session.phpsession.httponly] => 
[session.authtoken.cookiename] => SimpleSAMLAuthToken
[session.rememberme.enable] => 
[session.rememberme.checked] => 
[session.rememberme.lifetime] => 1209600
[memcache_store.servers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [hostname] => localhost
                    )

            )

    )

[memcache_store.prefix] => 
[memcache_store.expires] => 129600

[theme.use] => default
[template.auto_reload] => 
[production] => 1
[assets] => Array
    (
        [caching] => Array
            (
                [max_age] => 86400
                [etag] => 
            )

    )

[idpdisco.enableremember] => 1
[idpdisco.rememberchecked] => 1
[idpdisco.validate] => 1
[idpdisco.extDiscoveryStorage] => 
[idpdisco.layout] => dropdown
[authproc.idp] => Array
    (
        [30] => core:LanguageAdaptor
        [45] => Array
            (
                [class] => core:StatisticsWithAttribute
                [attributename] => realm
                [type] => saml20-idp-SSO
            )

        [50] => core:AttributeLimit
        [99] => core:LanguageAdaptor
    )

[authproc.sp] => Array
    (
        [90] => core:LanguageAdaptor
    )

[metadatadir] => metadata
[metadata.sources] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => flatfile
            )

    )

[metadata.sign.enable] => 
[metadata.sign.privatekey] => 
[metadata.sign.privatekey_pass] => 
[metadata.sign.certificate] => 
[metadata.sign.algorithm] => http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
[store.type] => phpsession
[store.sql.dsn] => sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedatabase.sq3
[store.sql.username] => 
[store.sql.password] => 
[store.sql.prefix] => SimpleSAMLphp
[store.sql.options] => Array
    (
    )

[store.redis.host] => localhost
[store.redis.port] => 6379
[store.redis.username] => 
[store.redis.password] => 
[store.redis.prefix] => SimpleSAMLphp
[store.redis.mastergroup] => mymaster
[store.redis.sentinels] => Array
    (
    )

[proxymode.passAuthnContextClassRef] =>
```

)

Help for this I am stuck in redirect loop